# Problem paintComponent() is called but not work

Tags: java

I am creating a program similar to Paint which, however, allows drawing only through commands called from the command line. Previously I used `((Graphics2D) getGraphics) .drawLine ()` to draw on `panel` and it worked correctly but for various needs I have to use `paintComponent`.

My problem is that PaintPanel's paintComponent method is called correctly but it doesn't work.

```
public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
PaintPanel panel;
CommandLine cmd;

/**
 * Creates new form Frame
 */
public Frame() {
    initComponents();

    // Crea il pannello sul quale disegnare e lo inserisce
    panel = new PaintPanel(coordsLabel);
    panel.setSize(containerPanel.getSize());
    //panel.setVisible(true);
    add(panel);

    cmd = new CommandLine(panel);

    // Sistema la grafica
    linesList.setBackground(jPanel1.getBackground());
    inputCommand.requestFocus();
    colorLabel.setBackground(PaintPanel.COLOR_BLACK);
    colorLabel.setOpaque(true);
    widhtLabel.setText("Widht: " + cmd.getPanel().getWidth());
    heightLabel.setText("Height: " + cmd.getPanel().getHeight());
    labelLookCommand.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
}

/**
 * Invia il comando chiamando gli appositi metodi.
 */
private void sendTheCommand() {        
    if (inputCommand.getText().isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    outputCommandLine.setText("no output");

    // Se il comando è errato, stampa l'output
    CommandError error = cmd.newCommand(inputCommand.getText());
    if (error.getNumber() != 0) {
        outputCommandLine.setForeground(Color.RED);
        outputCommandLine.setText("Error n. " + error.getNumber() + ": " + error.getError());
        outputCommandLine.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    validate();
    repaint();

    printOnPanelLines();

    inputCommand.setText("");
    inputCommand.requestFocus();

    // Aggiorna le label della grandezza e colore
    sizeLabel.setText("Size: " + cmd.getPanel().getSizeLine());
    colorLabel.setBackground(cmd.getPanel().getColor());
}

private void printOnPanelLines() {
    linesList.removeAll();
    for (Line line : cmd.getPanel().getLines()) {
        linesList.add(line.toString());
    }
}

/* ... code ... */                        

private void inputCommandActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    sendTheCommand();
}
```

This is the paintComponent method of PaintPanel class

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("paintComponents()");
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(10, 10, 1100, 500);
}
```

I verified that paintComponent is called correctly through the `System.out.println()` method.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Sorry if I was too vague. By not working I mean that, from what is written in the code I expect you to draw a blue rectangle and instead it does not.

Comment: What is a PaintPanel? What is its size? Is it opaque or not? Where do you pack the frame?

Comment: It is opaque (I have used setOpaque(true) in PaintPanel costructor. Its dimensions are height 800 and widht 1400

Comment: What is containerPanel? What is its size? If your frame has not yet been made visible when you call containerPanel.getSize(), its size is probably zero, so you are setting your PaintPanel to zero size. Use a layout manager rather than trying to set the sizes yourself.